# MercerKernel and Kernel PCA using smile in Java

Tags: java, pca, smile

[Smile KPCA Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZDMH.png)
So, I came across the concept of Kernel PCA for feature extraction. Currently, I am using smile's Java jar for kernel pca. While reading about their code, I also have doubts about Mercer Kernel.

I want someone to explain the smile's java code of kernel PCA, what are the parameters to be passed, and define those parameters, where for example what they mean by MercerKernel <double[]> kernel. And can someone explain to me about the Mercer kernel?